# "Get the first row of each day" SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am the end-user of a SQL Server DB with multiple lines ordered by date.
Lets take this DB as an example:

| Amount | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 23.5 | 20210512010220111 |
| 24 | 20210512020220111 |
| 30 | 20210512030220111 |
| 1.2 | 20210513011020111 |
| 1000 | 20210513020220111 |
| 24 | 20210514100220111 |
| 240 | 20210514100220111 |

Be advised that the date is just a long that represent the date in the format: yyyymmddhhMMssfff.

I am trying to create a SQL query like this:
**"Get the first row of each day"**
So for the above example the result will be:

| Amount | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 23.5 | 20210512010220111 |
| 1.2 | 20210513011020111 |
| 24 | 20210514100220111 |

I saw this example in multiple sources:
https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-select-the-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/

The problem is when I tried it that was way too slow for me
the DB is storing hundreds of millions of rows (with 9 columns each)

A couple of weeks ago I used a similar(ish) query for a daily min, avg, max:

```
SELECT MIN(Amount), AVG(Amount), MAX(Amount)
FROM table
GROUP BY Date/1000000000
```

- the "/1000000000" is for days.

That worked quickly enough, if there is something similar to FIRST(Amount) that would be great.
Just to clarify, I am just an end-user, I have no saying over the overall structure of the DB.

Edit:
This is the query I tried and was too slow:

```
WITH added_row_number AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Date/1000000000 ORDER BY Date ASC) AS row_number
  FROM table
)
SELECT
  *
FROM added_row_number
WHERE row_number = 1;
```

EDIT 2:

I took inspiration from all the answers here and after some trial and error I found this query worked fast enough (adjusted query to suit the example DB, not the actual query I used):

```
SELECT OrgTable.*
FROM (
     SELECT *
     FROM Table
     -- WHERE statement on a uniq key column
) As OrgTable
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT MIN(Date) As ModTimeMin
     FROM Table
     -- WHERE statement on a uniq key column
     GROUP BY DATE/1000000000 
     --this sub query gets the time of the first transaction of each day 
) As MinTable
ON OrgTable.Date = MinTable.Date --this joins the relevant data to the times table
ORDER BY OrgTable.Date ASC
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so we may assist you in fixing it.

Comment: I added the query I tried.

Comment: Please update with additional information if none of the answers suffice - performance is a tricky thing that also considers what indexes you have etc.
Also one suggestion remove the `*` everywhere in favor of the actual columns.
You say you have no control over the structure, but you might also consider a VIEW with the "date" as an actual DATE type and index that/query from that.  Storing dates as a string this way is not suggested or optimal in any way

Comment: Thank you all. I edited the post to include the final query I used.

Comment: You might consider putting that in as an answer instead and accepting that then upvote those answers that also assisted your here in coming up with the solution while to smak the designer of the date column that is not a date with a newspaper Note I am NOT begging for points which is a bad practice but this would be the proper course here. However, DO at least place and accept as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something to affect

```
SELECT t.yyyy_mm_dd_date, table.*
FROM table
JOIN (
  SELECT SUBSTRING (Date, 1, 8) as yyyy_mm_dd_date, MIN(Date) as min_date
  FROM table
) t
ON t.min_date = table.Date
```

in general i find SQL queries to run fast with joins and aggregations (especially over their indices), so if can translate query to use those believe generally should run fairly fast

Answer (score 1):

The following may perform better than your original query as they use an existance check (or top clause) instead of reading all data, calculating row_number for all rows, then scanning the result. It will perform best if there is already an index on the [Date] column.

As you have duplicate [Date] values, the query could return different results each time it is executed unless a unique key column is included in the query.

```
create table  #t(
    [Id] int
    ,[Amount] decimal(10,2)
    ,[Date] bigint
);

create index idx_Date on #t([Date]);

insert #t values
(1, 23.5, 20210512010220111)
,(2, 24, 20210512020220111)
,(3, 30, 20210512030220111)
,(4, 1.2, 20210513011020111)
,(5, 1000, 20210513020220111)
,(6, 24, 20210514100220111)
,(7, 240, 20210514100220111);


-- Assuming that you have a unique key available
select
    *
    ,t1.[Date]/1000000000
from #t t1
where not exists (
    select *
    from #t t2
    where t1.[Date]/1000000000 = t2.[Date]/1000000000
    and (
        t2.[Date] < t1.[Date]
        or (
            t2.[Date] = t1.[Date]
            and t2.Id < t1.Id
        )
    )
);

--This is a kludge if you don't have a unique key available and may perform worse than your original query. Don't use this without testing it in a non production system first.
select
    *
    ,t1.[Date]/1000000000
from #t t1
where not exists (
    select *
    from #t t2
    where t1.[Date]/1000000000 = t2.[Date]/1000000000
    and (
        t2.[Date] < t1.[Date]
        or (
            t2.[Date] = t1.[Date]
            and t2.%%physloc%% < t1.%%physloc%% -- %%physloc%% is the File/Page/Slot for the row
        )
    )
);

-- Alternatively using top. Assumes a unique column is available
select
    t1.*
    ,t1.[Date]/1000000000
from #t t1
cross apply (
    select top 1 *
    from #t t2
    where t1.[Date]/1000000000 = t2.[Date]/1000000000
    order by Date, Id
) t2
where t1.Id = t2.Id

drop table #t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Feels like you can use a cte here and cast the date strings as actual DATE values (the last query) here is my sample using test data (you did not post the column types so I guessed)

Not 100% clear about the "date" column if it is an actual datetime, you can just cast as a date

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE (
    Amount NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,  
    [Date] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @mytable(Amount,[Date])
VALUES
    (3.5, '20210512010220111'),
    (24.0,  '20210512020220111'),
    (30.0,'20210512030220111'),
    (1.2,   '20210513011020111'),
    (1000.0,    '20210513020220111'),
    (24.0,  '20210514100220111'),
    (240.0, '20210514100220111')
;

SELECT 
    [Amount], 
    MAX(CAST( LEFT([Date], 8)  AS DATE)) AS NewDate
FROM @mytable
GROUP BY AMOUNT 
ORDER BY MAX(CAST( LEFT([Date], 8)  AS DATE)) DESC;


/* this is what we want perhaps: */
;
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    Amount,
    CAST(LEFT([Date], 8) AS DATE) AS MyDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(LEFT([Date], 8) AS DATE) ORDER BY CAST(LEFT([Date], 8) AS DATE) DESC) AS row_number
  FROM @mytable
)
SELECT
  *
FROM cte
WHERE row_number = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you!
I am not sure though what is the difference between the query I posted (which took too long) and the query you are suggesting, performance wise.

Comment: IF these are "real" datetime, you might consider and index on the date column or some other changes.